# Windows 2008 R2 Server: Network zones (Public / Private / Domain) Seem to change randomly

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-firewall, windows

So far on 2 occasions we have noticed that the network zones assigned to our server nics has been changed without any interaction on our part. This is out of a few hundred servers we manage.

Case 1) Server 2008R2, 2 Network Adapters. 1 x LAN labeled in the Domain zone, and 1 x SAN in the private zone. We noticed some SAN traffic was being blocked, and lo and behold the SAN nic now showed the Domain zone.

Case 2) Server 208R2, 2 Network Adapters. 1 x LAN labeled in the Domain zone, and 1 x SAN in the Private zone. Noticed SAN traffic being blocked, discovered the SAN nic had been labeled Public.

Manually setting the zones in secpol.msc resolved the issue, but I would like to know what caused the problem in the first place, so we might prevent it in the future.

Comment: I've run into this annoying thing as well, best to assign it like you have through GPO as even a brief disconnection from a network can cause it to change your zone type.

Comment: Are the iSCSI NIC's configured with any of the following: A default gateway? A DNS suffix? DNS servers in the DNS client settings? Also, is the iSCSI network isolated (physically different switches or VLAN's)?

Answer (score 1):

See if this applies: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2524478

> On a computer that is running Windows 7 or Windows Server 2008 R2, the
>   network location profile that is selected changes unexpectedly from
>   Domain to Public. Additionally, the firewall settings (these are
>   determined by the network location profile) change to the settings
>   that correspond to the Public network location profile. Therefore,
>   some outgoing connections may be blocked, and some applications may be
>   disconnected.

The recommended resolution is to install [a hotfix](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=2d0bbe59-e2b5-4207-a4a5-6dd15adb9da4).

I'm fighting something of the same issue - there are also local policy settings which can toggle public vs private, so you could force the state of the network via gpedit.msc